# Multiple fields validation in registration mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, field

In the registration view of my mvc3 project i want to validate multiple input fields.
To be more precise, i need to check whether the User (firstname, lastname, street and postal) already exists. I tried it with the [Remote] validation together with the AdditionalFields property but for me it seems to be the wrong approach to solve that. (but i could be wrong).

What would be the best way to do the multiple fields validation, so that all four fields are checked for input? Do i have to write a custom validation with data annotation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the database, right? Its not something you do in Attributes. What you need is a [custom MembershipProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers).

Comment: Yes, i do. I also do the Remote validation on some other fields. But in this case i need the validation of the 4 fields. I'll check you link. thanks

Comment: @user1553913: What exactly do you mean by remote validation? You mean validate when typing?

Comment: [Required( ErrorMessageResourceName="ErrorSign", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.Shared.ErrorMessages))]
        [Remote("CheckUserNameAndAdress", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", AdditionalFields = "FirstName, LastName, Street")]
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{5,5}$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorInvalidPostalCode", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Account.Register))]
        [Display(Name = "PostalCode", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Account.Register))]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

Comment: There you see the [Remote()]..that allows you to validate values

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is the right answer to part of your question:

```
public class User {
    [Required]
    public String FirstName {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public String LastName {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public String Postal {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public String Street {get;set;}
}
```

This should validate that all 4 fields have input (client-side or server-side or both).

Comment: Thanks, but i think that's not exactly what i need, because the combined input of the fields should be checked against values in the db. Any idea?